# Android - Unknown attribute style on a fragment tag

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting this warning in Android Studio 1.1.0: 
Unknown attribute style 
Full warning: The inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml

Here is the code snippet:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_logo"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_logo"
    style="@style/FragmentLogo"/>
```

The warning occurs on the style attribute.

I am using gradle and android build tools 21.1.2

Comment: Why don't you try again with Android Studio 1.5.1?

Comment: Seeing the same warning also in Android Studio 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

The style attribute is supported for Views (and by inheritance ViewGroups), so fragments don't support it.

Comment: no it doesn't let me build. Does anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 1):

For my configuration warning still exists but style works for fragments.
Eventually fragments supply View on onCreateView() so style should work.

```
Android Studio 2.2.3
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25
gradle-2.14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity and Fragment supports android:theme. So please try this:

```
android:theme="@style/FragmentLogo"
```